# Fantasy manga with a blue-haired female protagonist who has ice magic and a blond(?) male protagonist with fire magic. They're rivals

Tags: story-identification, manga, magic

Please help me find this manga. I forgot the name so I kept finding it.

It's set in a magical world, fantasy.
The protagonist is a blue haired female, she has ice magic.
(Her hair was originally brown, but later changes to blue after having her powers.)
There's a male lead with blonde hair (he's rich) and he has fire  magic.

Both protagonist are rivals on their school TT.

That's all I can remember TT. Please help me. I'm dying to find this manga for days.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[I Want to be a Receptionist in This Magical World](https://myanimelist.net/manga/120896/Mahou_Sekai_no_Uketsukejou_ni_Naritai_desu)'s protagonist Nunnaly is a student who, upon entering Dolan Academy and having her magical affinity assessed on the first day of class, has her hair color changed from a nondescript brown to the blue that can be seen on the cover:

[image: cover of "I Want to be a Receptionist in This Magical World" featuring the protagonist, a girl with blue hair, and her rival, a boy with blonde hair]

Her affinity with ice magic is so strong that, once it is awakened, causes her hair to change. Her blonde-haired rival, Lockmann, is the wealthy son of a nobleman, and the two are always at odds. His main magical affinity is with Fire, as you remember. The first volume of the manga deals with the ways in which Nunnaly is always coming in 2nd place to Lockmann, and her intense feelings of rivalry towards him.

Comment: OH MY GOD OH MY GOD OH MY GOD THANK YOU SO MUCH I OWE MY LIFE OF READING THANK YOU 

Comment: Really thank you so much, I love this story so much. Thankyou for answering so fast too  you made my day TT